# What happened to Harrison's first nanny?

Tags: character, dexter

In Dexter Season 5 Harrison's nanny looks like an important part of the story. She is the only one who passed the nanny interview held by Debra. She really even cares for Harrison. So why did she disappear in the start of season 6 ? I am unaware if it's mentioned later.

Comment: according to the dexter wiki she left the series with no in universe explanation. And there was no mention why Batista's younger sister Jamie took over the role as nanny.

Comment: @Jared you can post it as an answer with the wikia link you are telling about.

Comment: It doesn't matter--she was very good, and falls into the category of "forgotten character" Showtime dropped the ball, just as they did for the show in the final season. So many wonderful endings that could have been, for this wonderful show. But you notice all the "new Directors" getting their decorations towards the end, sort of came across as "to hell with the audience and the integrity of the story line through" all the great seasons. Murder Leguerta--kill Deb, leave Dex alone without his son--the nonesense had no end. What crap

Comment: While the given answer is correct in that it was a dropped character, one thing that does happen over the season is that Sonya starts noticing (and quietly disapproving) of how little Dexter interacts with Harrison. Even without the character being dropped, I was already expecting her to leave over this, as it seemed to bother her.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Dexter Wikia](http://dexter.wikia.com/wiki/), [Sonya](http://dexter.wikia.com/wiki/Sonya) left the show without any explanation. There was also no explanation as to why Angel Batista's younger sister Jamie took over from Sonya.

The Wikia page for Sonya also adds

> Sonya unfortunately fell into the category of characters that disappear between seasons. This is likely due to their contract only requiring their appearance for one season and/or Showtime deciding to drop them afterwards. It's assumed that Showtime felt a younger, more visually attractive woman was needed to replace her for on screen appearances.

According to IMDB, she took up another role *Corp & Anam* after season 5, so perhaps she was only contracted for 1 season and couldn't be obligated into another season.

Comment: I just like the character and she has more soul in her acting then Jamie. Anyways nice answer.

Answer (score 1):

I wondered this as well. I would assume it was because Dexter's late night activities caused a problem. Remember she had already quit once and warned him. He probably left her holding the bag again, like he often did to Jamie as well. The plot line likes to emphasize his role as a parent, but he often was an absent father, getting home with barely enough time to tell his child goodnight and often still letting the nanny tuck him in, then leaving again to go kill someone.

Answer (score 1):

From [Entertainment Weekly](https://ew.com/article/2011/06/22/dexter-season-6-scott-buck/), showrunner Scott Buck answered it himself:

> **Dexter’s son, Harrison, has a new nanny named Jamie (Aimee Garcia), who is the younger sister of Angel (David Zayas). First of all, what happened to Sonya (Maria Doyle Kennedy), the old nanny?**
>
> She was such a fantastic actress but we had kind of wasted her in a way that she wasn’t given enough to play, and it felt that by this time it was already a lost opportunity, unfortunately. We thought it was best to move on in a new direction.

So it seems they didn't see any potential for her future arc.